# how can sollve Problem related to null safety: A nullable expression can't be used as a condition

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

```
ChangeFavoritesModel? changeFavoritesModel;
  void changeFavorites(int productId) {
    favorites?[productId] = !favorites[productId];
    DioHelper.postData(
      url: FAVORITES,
      data: {
        'product_id': productId,
      },
      token: token,
    ).then((value) {
      changeFavoritesModel = ChangeFavoritesModel.fromJson(value.data);
      print(value.data);
      emit(ShopSuccessChangeFavoritesState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(ShopErrorChangeFavoritesState());
    });
  }
```

here,an error occurs:

`favorites?[productId] = !favorites[productId];`

and say:-

> A nullable expression can't be used as a condition. (Documentation)
> Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition.

Comment: either you check the null condition before you use or if it is not nullable, make sure it is    non nullable

Answer (score 0):

because `favorites` is nullable, so check null first

```
if (favorites != null) {
    favorites[productId] = !favorites[productId];
}
```

or if you could do an early return

```
if (favorites == null) {
    return;
}
```